# Spring Boot SOAP webservice with MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-ws

I would like to combine two Spring (spring-boot) applications from Spring guides:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Unfortunately, these examples do not work together. There is a problem with servlet dispatcher. After adding *dispatcherServlet* bean - MVC servlet is not working (*Error 404*).

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}
```

How to configure servlet dispatcher to work properly?

I would like to have:

- `localhost:8080/ws/*` - webservice
- `localhost:8080/web/*` - MVC components

Thanks in advance!

Comment: rename the method to `messageDispatcherServlet` instead of `dispatcherServlet` the latter overrides the default configured `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in the registration of the `MessageDispatcherServlet` due to the name `dispatcherServlet` it overrides the by Spring Boot registered `DispatcherServlet`. The latter is needed for the MVC part of your website.

To fix it just rename your method to anything but `dispatcherServlet` say `messageDispatcherServlet`.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}
```

Comment: @m-deinum I have a simular MessageDispatcherServlet but it's configured to consume the '/*' url pattern. I want to add a MVC servlet which will reply to '/ui' pattern. Can i add a filter or something to MessageDispatcherServlet so it checks '/ui' pattern first and delegates, else it handles the request as a standard SOAP message. Thanks

Comment: Why would you need a filter? The servlet container handles this for you, just map the server to the correct pattern.